# Intellisense doesn't work on certain scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been using vscode for editing my unity scripts but lately I haven't been able to use autocomplete for my scripts, for some reason on my older projects intellisense seems to work fine but any new project I try to use it and it just doesn't work, here is the omnisharp output: (and yes, I've installed the targeting pack for this framework version).

I also tried reinstalling vscode and resetting the settings, nothing seemed to work.

```
    Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'c:\Users\Lincoln\Documents\Prototype SI' on host 7244.
    The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
    Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\Lincoln\Documents\Prototype SI\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
```

c:\Users\Lincoln\Documents\Prototype SI\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
C:\Users\Lincoln.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.18.0.omnisharp\1.32.11\msbuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1126,5): Error: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

```
    Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\Lincoln\Documents\Prototype SI\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
    Miscellaneous file: c:\Users\Lincoln\Documents\Prototype SI\Assets\Player.cs added to workspace
```

Comment: Hi, sadly i cant help, but im really intrested why would somone use vs code over visual studio?

Comment: Even more when VS Community is free.

Comment: because my laptop is really old and my hardware struggles to run vs, and also i like how it's design is simpler than vs

Comment: I see, yeah thats a good reason vs code is more lightweight thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try to locate the project folder from vs code. click the open folder from vs code and navigate to your project.